# Javascript - missing ] after element list

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
     var inf = { PID: pid, PDate: pdate};
```

I then have a call to the function

```
     SetVal(inf);


    function SetVal(inf) {

      alert(inf.PID);
```

-- the above works fine. I show the alert fine

But if I have it has a hyperlink which makes a call to SetVal it does not work:

```
     valset =  '<li><a href=\'javascript:SetVal(' + inf + ');\' ><h3> ' + this.PID + '</h3><p>'

    $('#DataSet).html(valset);
```

When I click on the hyperlink I get the following message in FireBug:

missing ] after element list

Not sure how to resolve it. I thought they would be one in the same.

Comment: Not sure if its a mispaste or the issue, but your missing a `'` in `$('#DataSet')`

Comment: If you're trying to reference the `inf` variable in the inline handler, then you shouldn't be concatenating its value. `<a href=\'javascript:SetVal(inf);\' >` This assumes that `inf` is a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable "inf" is an object, but you're trying to treat it as a string when you build that element.  You'd be much better off just doing it with jQuery:

```
$('#DataSet').html($('<li/>')
  .append($('<a/>', {
    href: function() { SetVal(inf); },
  }))
  // ...
```